# SSL | Error WARNING: cannot verify certificate

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ssl, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

Last week one of my domains stopped loading http content.
Domain pings, apache is active, I restarted apache.
It looks like the reason is there is a problem with the SSL certificate.

Should I just do a new certificate using Certbot?

https://pastebin.com/Zf8WkxLi

Comment: If you read the log (which you should add to this question, not place in pastebin) you'll see the last line is `20 redirections exceeded.`  Before that are multiple lines saying `301 Moved Permanently` and `[following]`.  Your web server is misconfigured and causing a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been *already* using Certbot with this domain until now, then no. The bad certificate is not the main problem – it's an indicator of another problem.

Notice that the current certificate isn't from Let's Encrypt anymore (or even from any CA at all) – it is a self-signed certificate that was automatically generated by the server. That's a very different situation from merely having a certificate that's expired, it means the web server isn't even looking at the correct file.

It is possible that your Apache configuration lost its <VirtualHost> configuration for this domain, so it no longer knows what certificate to use – and also no longer knows what webpages to serve. Check whether `ServerName orcaaccounting.com` is still present in your httpd config.

(It's also possible that your DNS domain has been changed to point to a different server entirely...)

Comment: Got it! It was the IP of the A record was pointed to the wrong IP.  This happened when my software had to regenerate DNS through GoDaddy API. So basic...